# Will Windows use NFS to write to a self mapped share?

Tags: windows, nfs

If a Windows server has a drive mapped to a share on the same server, will it still use NFS to read/write or does it know that the drive is actually local? Would I/O performance be improved by using a local path or non-local block level storage device (assuming good network performance)?

The current configuration writes to logical drive Z: which is mapped to a share on physical drive D:.

```
C:\
D:\data\share
Z:\                         (mapped to \\HOST\data\share)
```

Comment: Have you attempted this and tested it, using something like wireshark?

Comment: Windows file sharing doesn't use NFS, NFS is a UNIX thing.

Comment: @mfinni unfortunately I am trying to debug a Windows server under load from my Mac and VirtualBox didn't get me anything conclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a "mapped" drive letter (or a UNC path) is going to send your I/O requests through a much longer software pipeline than addressing the physical drive through its "local" drive letter. There's a [Stack Overflow question with some benchmarks in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903054/unc-path-pointing-to-local-directory-much-slower-than-local-access) to give you an idea of what the impact looks like.

Comment: I am wondering now (I can check in a little bit) if the traffic travels through the local NIC or not.

Comment: Not physically through the NIC, but definitely through the network stack.